# Simplify this unnecessary javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that there has to be a better way to handle this, but I can't figure it out.

I need 8 different random numbers generated to be used as `val`s for some `selects`. The following script works, but there must be a simpler way.

```
$('#test12').click(function() {
        $('#narrative').fadeOut('fast');
    $('#narrative').empty();
var numb1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
var numb2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
var numb3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
var numb4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
var numb5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
var numb6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
var numb7 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
var numb8 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
        $("#sel1").val(numb1).change();
        $("#sel2").val(numb2).change();
        $("#sel3").val(numb3).change();
        $("#sel4").val(numb4).change();
        $("#sel5").val(numb5).change();
        $("#sel6").val(numb6).change();
        $("#sel7").val(numb7).change();
        $("#sel8").val(numb8).change();
    });
```

Comment: How about a `for` loop?

Comment: @Pointy Can you get me started and I'll hack together the rest?

Comment: `for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++) { ... }` - [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: This question may be better suited on code review SE. On another note yes just use a for loop and you can make 16 lines 4.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace What's code review? Haven't seen that before.

Comment: [codereview.se] is another site on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks. I figured it out. Gotta work more with `for` loops.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com A place for asking for help with improving code but not necessarily errors.

Comment: This may be appropriate for Code Review, given that **A** the code works **B** the code isn't hypothetical or incomplete in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val) can take a function, which avoids needing to loop (because jQuery will be doing it for you internally). You'll want to give all your `#selN` nodes a class as well to simplify the selection:

```
$('#test12').click(function() {
    $('#narrative').fadeOut('fast').empty();
    $('.sel').val(function () {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
    }).change();
});
```

Alternatively you could write out the full selector:

```
$('#sel1, #sel2,...#sel8').val(...
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Pretty simple solution. Didn't know `.val()` could take a function.

Answer (score 3):

Use a loop to and use the index to modify the selector

```
$('#test12').click(function() {
     $('#narrative').fadeOut('fast');
     $('#narrative').empty();

     for(var i=1;i<=8;i++){
        var numb = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
        $("#sel"+i).val(numb).change();
    }
});
```